# Can you cast a string of a float number into an integer in python? (in 1 step)

Tags: python, type-conversion, integer

Example:

```
string = "12.4"
x = int(string)
```

Just curious if there's a way to do this directly, or if you just have to convert to float then to int as 2 steps.

Comment: As far as I know, you can only do `x = int(float(string))`

Comment: yeah there is no other way, but because all integers are a float, so it makes sense, or you can check if is actually an integer ("12.4".isdigit()) and then convert it to float or an int

Comment: `int(x.split('.')[0])` -- but that isn't robust since it would fail for things like `'1e4'`.

Answer (score -1):

```
x="12.4"
x=int(float(x))# this float(x) first converts the string x into float and 
#then int() function converts now newly float x int int x
```